# Spork and db:test:prepare

Tags: rspec, migration, cucumber, spork

Simple question which I hope has some clever answer.

I use Spork to run my specs and my features.  Works great. However, if I update my database with a migration, I can't update the test database without stopping the both of the spork servers.  Is there anyway that I can get spork to let me drop and recreate the database without shutting it down?

The reason I ask is because I can run migrations while my dev server runs, and it seems to me that I'm doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same issue and found this: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/188

per the recommendation there I added:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
```

to the end of the Spork.prefork block in both spec_helper.rb and env.rb